Keycloak Setup Issues: Works with localhost but not with Domain Name
I'm currently working on deploying Keycloak using a StatefulSet in a GKE cluster. I've set up a load balancer service to expose Keycloak, but I'm facing issues accessing Keycloak with my domain name. Here's the relevant configuration:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  serviceName: "keycloak-headless"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: keycloak-sa
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
          args: ["start"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
            - containerPort: 8443
              name: https
          volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-tls-volume
              mountPath: /etc/x509/https
              readOnly: true
          env:
            - name: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME
            - name: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            - name: KC_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_DB
            - name: KC_DB_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_DB_URL
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HOSTNAME
            - name: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_DB_USERNAME
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_DB_PASSWORD
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
              value: "/etc/x509/https/tls.crt"
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
              value: "/etc/x509/https/tls.key"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /health/ready
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /health/live
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "2000m"
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak-tls-volume
          secret:
            secretName: keycloak-tls
      tolerations:
        - key: "keycloak"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoSchedule"



This is my service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: jgroup
    port: 7600
    targetPort: 7600
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None

This is my ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/enable-global-access: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - houseofllm.com
      secretName: keycloak-tls
  rules:
    - host: houseofllm.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: keycloak-service
                port:
                  number: 8080


What Works:
Port Forwarding: When I enable port forwarding using kubectl port-forward keycloak-0 8443:8443 -n default, I can access Keycloak at https://localhost:8443, and everything works fine.
What Doesn't Work:
Domain Name Access: When I try to access Keycloak using my domain name (e.g., https://mydomainname.com:8443 or https://mydomainname.com), I receive an error saying "Safari cannot find the server."
Additional Information:
I have a valid TLS certificate configured in the Keycloak setup.
Questions:

Why does it work with localhost but not with the domain name
Are there any specific configurations I need to       check for the
Keycloak service or load balancer?

I narrowed it down to an issue with the ingress as the backend config is unhealthy. But I still don't know why it's unhealthy.
If i don't use ingress and use a service load balancer then everthing works. The following configuration works.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  serviceName: "keycloak-service"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: keycloak-sa
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
          args: ["start","--cache-stack=kubernetes", "--spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
            - containerPort: 8443
              name: https
            - name: jgroups
              containerPort: 7600
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
          volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-tls-volume
              mountPath: /etc/x509/https
              readOnly: true
          env:
            - name: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_USERNAME
            - name: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_BOOTSTRAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            - name: KC_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_DB
            - name: KC_DB_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_DB_URL
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HOSTNAME
            - name: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HEALTH_ENABLED
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_DB_USERNAME
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_DB_PASSWORD
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE
            - name: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-secrets
                  key: KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE
            - name: KC_PROXY
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_PROXY
            - name: jgroups.dns.query
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: JGROUPS_DNS_QUERY
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
            - name: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_METRICS_ENABLED
            - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
            - name: KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HOSTNAME_URL
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_HOSTNAME_URL
            - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
            - name: KC_LOG_LEVEL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: keycloak-configmap
                  key: KC_LOG_LEVEL
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "2000m"
      volumes:
        - name: keycloak-tls-volume
          secret:
            secretName: keycloak-tls
      tolerations:
        - key: "keycloak"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoSchedule"



apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: jgroup
    port: 7600
    targetPort: 7600
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: LoadBalancer

Ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 2500m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 12k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: houseofllm.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak-service
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /keycloak/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Hello. Do you have more error logs by any chance? When you find "Safari cannot find the server.", what logs do you can from the service itself?

Also, since you are using latest keycloak version, KC_PROXY should be replaced with KC_PROXY_HEADERS: "xforwarded" ref Hope this helps!

What port and paths does keyclock listen and returns health-check info on ?

I'm not entirely sure, but in my working configuration, I see the host is also passed to the start command which I don't see in yours
start --optimized --hostname=<your_domain_name>

